# How to test memory leak using Valgrind in a process running as daemon in Linux

Tags: c, linux, memory-leaks, valgrind

I know how to test for memory leaks using Valgrind: You have to start a C program in the foreground under Valgrind and later send a kill signal using `Ctrl+C` to see the leak report. It does not the show leak report while the program is running.

So how can we use Valgrind with a process running as daemon in Linux. I can not start the process manually in the foreground. Is there a workaround/solution for this?

I have tried searching for the option to attach to an already running process with Valgrind.

Comment: You cannot attach valgrind to a running process, you need to figure out a way to start it as a daemon with valgrind.

Comment: it will be really difficult if the program is already running in a docker container. say, if we start the program under valgrind, how will we get leak report without killing the running process?

Comment: You can also try other leak analysis tools such as https://github.com/WuBingzheng/memleax

Comment: Maybe you could use the compiler's sanitize options. (e.g.) Compile with `-fsanitize=address`. You would only have to have the (e.g. `systemd`) script divert `stderr` to a file.

Comment: "I know how to test for memory leaks using Valgrind". That's funny. And about as far from being correct as is possible. You don't have to kill the process with ctrl-c. memcheck can produce reports while running.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to attach Valgrind to a running process.

Valgrind does not work in the same way as debuggers and tracers.

With a debugger, there are two processes. The debugger and the 'inferior'. (Actually there may be more than one 'inferior'). The debugger controls the inferior via the ptrace syscall (on Linux, which you've tagged).

Valgrind has a single process which is divided into two parts. The 'host' which is running on the real CPU and provides the virtualized environment. Then there is the 'guest' which is the exe you are testing which runs in this virtualized environment. From the operating system perspective there is just one process.

Transferring a running process into Valgrind would entail

- Loading the exe into memory. Doable.
- Replicating the exe registers. Doable.
- Transferring the exe stack.
- Transferring the exe heap.
- Transferring internal state from libc libthread (file descriptors, sockets, threads etc.)

memcheck would not be able to regenerate the allocation history and history of memory initialization.

Transferring the allocation control structures would be a major challenge. It would require knowing which allocator is being used (glibc, ptmalloc, jemalloc etc.) and also knowing exactly where in memory these control blocks are and being able to pick apart their binary content in memory. If for any reason any allocated memory blocks needed to be moved, it would be necessary to fixup any pointers to that memory.

Then there's all the problems related to PIDs and LWP IDs - the new process won't have the same values.

There are probably many more things I haven't thought of as well.